# How to send file with http

Tags: file, .net-core, stream

I am trying from a `.net` client to download a file via a `.net` server (file is located on server machine ) using the `StreamContent`.However when launching the request i am getting the exception:

**Exception**

`Stream does not support reading.`

**Client**

```
class Program {
        static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("txt.path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
                var content = new StreamContent(stream);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5300/get", content);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Server**

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            string fname = "dld.txt";

            app.Run(async (context) => {
                if (!(context.Request.Path == "get")) {
                    return;
                }
                File.WriteAllText(fname, "data is:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                using (Stream stream = context.Response.Body) {
                    await fs.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble getting the file because i wanted to use the `Request.Body` stream as a sink.I wanted the `server` to write the data on this stream (i thought the `Request` stream can be used both ways).

I have solved it by using the `Response` stream instead:

**Client**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)) {
                var content = new StringContent("not important");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5300/get",content);
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use like this:

```
HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(paramString); //if you want to use string
HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(paramFileStream); //if you want to use  file stream
HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(paramFileBytes);// if you want to use aray of bytes
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        formData.Add(stringContent, "param", "param");
        formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file", "file");
        formData.Add(bytesContent, "file", "file");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("some URL", formData);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    }
}
```